# Peek function errors

Tags: c, string

Hi all I'm trying to write a peek function, but I'm confused about how to fix the warnings I'm getting. My goal is to return a NULL character if the size is zero, else return the last character.

```
struct mystring
{
  char size;
  char capacity;
  char* data;
};
typedef struct mystring Mystring;


     char* mystring_peek(MYSTRING hString)
     {
       Mystring* string = (Mystring*) hString;
       if(string != NULL)
       {
         if(string->size != NULL)//line containing first warning
         {
           return &(string->data);//line containing second warning 
         }
     }
      return;
     }
```

Errors/Warnings using gcc -Wall

```
   warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
   warning: return from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]​
```

Comment: What is the definition of `Mystring`?

Comment: Peek/Poke - Commodor 64 - Apart from that reference where is the declaration of MYSTRING?

Comment: My fault I'll edit my post to include the Mystring struct

Comment: Why do you expect us to guess what your types are?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan @M Thotager both of your answers really helped me and all my warnings/errors are resolved

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes I do. I was using the char type for my comparisons which was the root cause for my mismatches. I switched to your answer because your description was what helped me most thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first warning is, as the compiler says, because you compare a pointer and an integer. The code should read:

```
if(string->size != 0)
```

The second error is a simple type mismatch. You return `char**` when `char*` is required. You presumably mean:

```
return string->data;
```

Surely the compiler objects to:

```
return;
```

After all, you did promise to return a `char*`.

One also wonders about the cast from `MYSTRING` to `Mystring*`.

Answer (score 1):

Find the modified function

```
  char* mystring_peek(MYSTRING hString)
  {
      Mystring* string = (Mystring*) &hString;
      if(string != NULL)
      {
         if(string->size != 0)
         {
            return string->data;
         }
      }

     return NULL;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why this line

```
 Mystring* string = (Mystring*) hString;
```

It does not make any sense as `hString` is of type `Mystring`

There is where things fall apart.

Answer (score 0):

&(char-data) is char ** instead of char*,
at the end of the function should rather be return NULL
and size should be compared with 0 instead of NULL.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (string->size != NULL) // line containing first warning
```

gives a warning because `size` is an integer, but `NULL` expands to a pointer type on your implementation. Use `0` or `'\0'` instead of `NULL`.